# Sort by Two Levels of Columns Using Counter to Determine Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort a table in vba (in the middle of a larger macro) by two levels.  I tried recording the macro doing exactly what I wanted but the range was specific to that series of data.  The end of the range can change so I added a counter to the code to basically tell me where the range ends

what I have below is a simplified version of my code (I set the counter to 200 to simplify things but this will change in my code)

What I want is to sort the range ("A1, "AB" & counterT) by column C and then by column A so if there is an easier way to do this (which I assume there is) feel free to ignore my code.

I paused in my code (as you will notice below) to highlight the part that is really giving me the trouble. However I´m not entirely sure if I fix that part that the code will still work so that might just be a current problem and not the whole issue.
Thank you for any help!

```
Sub Sort

Dim counterT As Long
counterT = 200

Dim rDataToSort As Range, rSortData As Range

Set rSortData = Range("C4", C" & CounterT)

Set rDataToSort = Range("A4", AB" & CounterT)
```

I'm pausing the code here cause I don´t know how to add the second level (column A) here

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Sort

.SortFields.Clear
.SortFields.Add Key:=rSortData, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
.SetRange rDataToSort
.Header = xlNo
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply

End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...it was a lot easier than I thought haha this is the except from the code that is necessary assuming "counter is already defined and set

```
Workbooks("ChainRetailerMacro.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet4").Range("A1", "U" & counter).Sort _
key1:=Sheets("sheet4").Range("A1", "A" & counter), order1:=xlAscending, _
key2:=Sheets("sheet4").Range("C1", "C" & counter), order2:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm less sure about sorting, but for counting, try:

```
Counter = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A:A"))
```

Also, when defining the first sort condition, you seem to have three lots of  " in the Range statement:

```
Range("C2: ("C" & counter))
```

Finally, you could try looping through the sort conditions:

```
Dim rangeID As Variant
with ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    For Each rangeID In Array("C2: (C" & counter), "A2:A1512")
        .SortFields.Add Key:- .Range(rangeID), SortOn........
    Next
.setrange range("A:C")
.header = xlYes
end with
```

Comment: sorry about my initial question it wasn´t as clear. I edited my code to reflect the actual ranges I desire (as they were wrong before). The looping through the sort conditions makes sense and I think it would work but I can´t seem to turn your code into something functioning can you please elaborate a little bit (I don´t understand what to put in the "......." part) also it´s giving me an error on the "key:-" part which I presume is because of the dash.  Thanks again for any help you can give